# how to remove horizontal break/shift line in camera using opencv C++

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, v4l2

I have a C++ program that display real time video capture from my Logitech C920.

Before it start to capture frames, the program run the following configuration in order to prepare the camera

```
void configure_camera(VideoCapture &video) {
    video.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280);
    video.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720);
    video.set(cv::CAP_PROP_AUTO_EXPOSURE,1);
    video.set(cv::CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE, 5);
}
```

The problem is when I stop the program and run it again, a horizontal line appers in the screen. The problem is when I try to set the exposure more then once in the same USB camera, that line appers in the screen. So, in order to change the exposure value, i have to remove the usb camera and put it again in order to change the exposure value without having a horizontal line in the screen.

[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUTyK.png)

Comment: Are you releasing your VideoCapture object?  See here. https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html

Comment: that shouldn't make a difference because RAII/destructor is getting called for sure -- likely firmware/driver bug, is my bet anyway. logitech is famous for raking in the money on the c920, hardware that is 10 years old. they make better ones now, with better software/firmware